# Android in eclipse work with bitbucket always error

Tags: android, eclipse, bitbucket, android-build

I'm a newbie to `bitbucket` and `android`. I create a repository on bitbucket and clone it into my computer, then I commit my android project and push it to remote repository, then I close eclipse.

After reopening my android project, I found that the folder (build path) with the named `Android Private Libraries` and `Android Dependencies` were lose away (that's mean lose reference libraries), that cause my project many errors.

**How can I build path to reference to necessary libraries?**

More over, I also found that all the libraries before always reference to the project with the named `appcompat_v7` in the eclipse workspace.

I'm not so sure it would work correctly if I clone my project from another computer.

**Please help me to work correctly between android `eclipse` with `bitbucket`**

Comment: I think this problem is due to your gitignore file. Try to make it robust.

Comment: That's exactly, but how can I get rid of this error with gitignore files.

Comment: Try to make gitignore using vogila tutorial. After that fix the dependencies error in your project. Make new repository on bitbucket. And pull code to that repository. Now to further commits and fetch problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Once you restart your eclipse if you do a project clean and build it again your dependencies should be fine.

app_compat won't give you errors as long as you have all the API levels that are required by you application.
Make sure to update your sdk